# How to properly export a 3d kitchen sink model that uses subdivision surface to Unreal Engine?

Tags: export, subdivision-surface, unreal-engine

I have a very basic model that resembles a kitchen sink. When I export it to unreal engine with the default settings for FBX, the model imports with the sink park deformed and lacking metallic silver color material. Perhaps there is something specific I need to change in export settings?

Here's how the model looks like in blender:
[image]

Here's how it imports in unreal engine:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.fbx export why there are no materials or textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures)

Comment: Partially. So I now understand that metallic material cannot be exported, as far as the sink shape it can't either? However I still don't know what I should do